# how to use rails format.json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
def index
@cellphones = Cellphone.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @cellphones }
end
```

- SIMPLE ANSWERS PLEASE...

  - what is **format.json** used for?
  - do I have to create a view for it?
  - how does it relate to **javascrip**?
  - how does it relate to to **ajax**?
  - please give a simple example of how to use it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. It's used to return JSON.
2. No, it renders `@cellphones` as JSON. You *may* create a view, though, for example, using a JSON builder to customize the output beyond what Rails provides out of the box.
3. JavaScript is often used to make JSON Ajax requests, like for client-side frameworks.
4. Ajax calls often want JSON as a result. They may also request HTML to render directly.
5. That *is* an example of how to use it; make an Ajax request to `/cellphones`.